# How to move all images in a post to a single gallery for a bunch of posts?

Tags: posts, images, gallery

So, I have just addded bunch of blog posts, just pasting the pictures as seperate pictures. Now, I want to switch to using galleries for ALL of the posts. Any idea how? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! Can you please clarify your question? It's not answerable in its current state. What editor are you using? Where are you pasting your pictures? Are you using the image as your featured image or putting them somewhere on the page? What are you hoping to use for your gallery (gutenberg gallery, plugin, or hard-coded, etc)?